# Tools needed for OS Development and Emulation

Tags: osdev

I saw lots of Good Tutorials about OS Development, but i don't know how to setup an emulator and test my OS. I also don't know which bootloader to choose, because i don't want to use GRUB - my OS will be lightweight and GRUB is heavy.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS do you use for development? On a Mac, I would recommend Qemu as the emulator. On Linux, Qemu or boots. On Windows, bochs.

Do you have a cross compiler? (A compiler that creates executables for the architecture and platform you want to target your OS to.) If not, read [this page on osdev.org](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler).

Bootloader is a difficult question.
The hard way is to create your own, which took me about half a year. Read a lot at osdev.org and brokenthorn.com if that is your path.
Otherwise, it depends on your desired architecture (i.e. x86, x86_64, ARM), executable format (i.e. ELF, PE, Mach-O), device (i.e. hard disk, floppy), file system (i.e. EXT2, FAT12, FAT32) and firmware (BIOS, UEFI):

- UEFI: Take a look at Gummiboot etc.
- BIOS: Gujin might be OK, but is also huge. Runs on x86 and x86_64.
- If you want to target ARM, I have no information as I do not know anything about it.
- If you want to target x86_64 with ELF as the file format, hard disk as the device and FAT32 as the file system, you could take a look at [my bootloader](http://github.com/leitimmel/bootforce).

**(NOTE: I am not trying to advertise anything.)**